# Unable to get rows of table using xpath

Tags: python, scrapy

```
class Myspider(scrapy.Spider):
   name = "brickset_spider"
   start_urls = ['https://www.sahibinden.com/en/cars/used?date=1day&a5_min=2005&a5_max=2020']

   def parse(self,response):

    print("inside")
    print(response)
    rows = response.xpath("/html/body/div[4]/div[4]/form/div/div[3]/table/tbody")

    print("rows")
    print(rows)
    for row in rows:
        year = row.css('td:nth-child(4) a::text').extract_first()  # extract year from every row
        link = row.css('td:nth-child(4) a::attr(href)').extract_first()
        date = row.css('td:nth-child(8) a::text').extract_first()
        print(row)
```

I want to get link to ads in this table and also date posted. But when I print it its empty
[image]

This is stacktrace:

```
inside
<200 https://www.sahibinden.com/en/cars/used?date=1day&a5_min=2005&a5_max=2020>
rows
[]
```

Comment: Since that URL presents a login screen, you ~should have~ will have to bear the responsibility of distilling it to an [MCVE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve), but if I were a betting person, I'd bet the table data is being loaded via XHR, so check your network console

Comment: @mdaniel it's not. Site has a very strict security. I can't view it in there.